# What is the song in the hospital scene in The Godfather

Tags: analysis, soundtrack, the-godfather

In the first Godfather movie, when Michael Corleone goes to the hospital to check up on his father, he notices that all the guards are missing. There is a very very trippy song playing in the background. The chorus just keeps repeating, and it sounds something like "Mi in haw..."

Does anyone know what song this is and why Coppola chose to go with this song?

Answer (score 5):

The music playing in that specific scene does not appear to have a specific name, but it is part of the original score composed for the movie by Nino Rota.  You can read an analysis of the entire score at the [Damn, That's Some Fine Tailoring](http://web.archive.org/web/20141110003135/https://dtsft.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/whats-the-score-the-godfather/) blog.